# How can I find document by objectId and one more field in mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to find a document by ObjectId and one more field in mongodb using nodejs. But the problem is that I am passing id in the form of string and want to match it with objectId of the document.
Help me

```
module.exports.getProduct = function(id, callback){
 //here id is "59f5v26sdf4grgbawf"
    var query = {_id : id , status : "approved"};
//and _id is in the form of ObjectId("59f5v26sdf4grgbawf")
    Product.find(query, callback)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert a string to Object.

If you are using Mongoose, then it will looks like that:

```
var query = {_id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) , status : "approved"};
```