# Mongoose findById returns null even with valid id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have already seen the discussion about the following question with a similar title 
[mongoose 'findById' returns null with valid id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906859/mongoose-findbyid-returns-null-with-valid-id)
But my problem is not the database name since all my other connections with the same database in fact the queries on the same collection are working fine.
I am using mongoose 4.13.6, node js 6.11 and mongo 3.4.
It is a post request .

```
var query=req.body;
```

I am sending the search parameters as

```
var findFruit = 
{
    _id:query._id
}
```

When I print my findFruit I get :

```
_id:'5a1cf77920701c1f0aafb85e'
```

The controller function for this is :

```
Fruit.findById(findFruit._id,function(err,fruit){
        if( _.isNull(err) ){
            var response = genRes.generateResponse(true,"found successfully");
            callback(response);
        }
        else{
            var response = genRes.generateResponse(false,"there occured some error : "+err);
            callback(response);
        }
    })
```

I even tried find

```
Fruit.find(findFruit,function(err,fruit){
        if( _.isNull(err) ){
            var response = genRes.generateResponse(true,"found successfully");
            callback(response);
        }
        else{
            var response = genRes.generateResponse(false,"there occured some error : "+err);
            callback(response);
        }
    })
```

The collection for sure has the entry under this id .

I went through this git issue as well https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3079
Unfortunately I cannot downgrade mongoose as it might affect multiple other working functions.
Edit :
I tried creating ObjectId like :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var objectId = new ObjectID();
// Convert the object id to a hex string
var originalHex = objectId.toHexString();
// Create a new ObjectID using the createFromHexString function
var newObjectId = new ObjectID.createFromHexString(query._id);
```

The model file :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var FruitSchema = new Schema({
    name : {type : String, unique : true},
    color : {type : String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Fruit', FruitSchema);
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an `ObjectId` from `_id` string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find document by objectId and one more field in mongodb using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456457/how-can-i-find-document-by-objectid-and-one-more-field-in-mongodb-using-nodejs)

Comment: @Héctor Yes, I posted  an edit to the question with my code about how I did it

Comment: @Neodan I tried the solution there , it didn't work for me

Comment: You should create the ObjectId with: `newObjectId = new ObjectID(query._id)`

Comment: @Héctor Thanks! But it didnt work the outcome of this is still 5a1cf77920701c1f0aafb85e.

Comment: Could you show the schema definition?

Comment: @Hector I edited the question and pasted it

Comment: Have you tried making the query from a mongodb terminal? Also, try Fruit.findOne({_id: query._id })

Comment: @Héctor db.fruits.find({ "_id" : ObjectId("56672a335dc18d13242fffd4") }).pretty() this one works . But this doesnt  db.fruits.find({ _id : "56672a335dc18d13242fffd4" }).pretty()

Comment: Are you connected to the correct database? You can use `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to debug the queries that mongoose creates.

Comment: @MikaS yes I am connected to the correct database. Thanks for your suggestion , so I added this and the outcome was fruits.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a1cf66920701c1f0aafb85e") }, { fields: {} })

Comment: @MikaS turning debug on really helped

Comment: Converting the string into objectId then calling find by sending _id as the parameter worked for me. Can't understand why findbyid didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still trying to figure out why findById didn't work for me but the following piece of code did it

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var newObjectId=new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(query._id);
var params={
            '_id':newObjectId
}
Fruit.find(params).exec(function (err,fruit) {
if( _.isNull(err) ){
        var response = genRes.generateResponse(true,"found successfully");
        callback(response);
    }
    else{
        var response = genRes.generateResponse(false,"there occured some error : "+err);
        callback(response);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

All my findById("id") calls returned null.

When looking at the collection with Compass I realized that all my _id elements were Strings. Note that the entire collection was imported.

I created a new element in Compass and the _id was created as ObjectId! and when I called findById("id") with that element's id it worked!

My conclusion is that there is obviously a bug with import. I have not found a way to convert the string _id fields to ObjectId's in the actual collection.

Comment: _id: { type: mongoose.ObjectId, required: true },

Answer (score 2):

> All my findById("id") calls returned null, when _id elements are Strings.

## In the first place:

Check your mongodb database, if `_id` is stored as `String`, findById(id) can not find since it identifies `ObjectId`. If you've used import database by using `mongoimport` command and including _id in JSON:

- **Solution 1:**

  modify your JSON and for each document, change `_id` for instance:

  `_id: "5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e"` to the following and run `mongoimport` again:

```
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e" }
```

- **Solution 2:**

  delete _id in the JSON file, drop collection and import again. Mongo will auto-create _id.

After any of solutions above, `findById("id")` will work.

## **Secondly:**

Specifically in such cases where your `_id` elements are string, might be a better idea to use `mongodb` package: `npm i mongodb`

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("your_db_name");
    dbo.collection("fruits_collection")
       .find({_id:'5a1cf77920701c1f0aafb85e'})
       //.find({_id:'5a1cf77920701c1f0aafb85e'}, { projection: { _id: 0, name: 1, color: 1} }) // to select specific columns desired
      .toArray(function (err, result) {
           if (err) throw err;
           console.log(result);
           db.close();
    });
});
```

The above simple code, assumed you manage error handling yourself, either through `try-catch`, or 
sending `404` as status code, or redirect to error page template, depending on whether  the code is embedded in the Express route handler or not.

Hope this helped .. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Shoom. Yes, worked for me, thanks.  findById() expects ObjectID, not a String.

I did not have a constraint to create documents with a specific id, so I imported with no _id.  The db had newly-assigned _id as ObjectID.

findById(id), (and updateOne({ _id: id }, ...), started working as expected.