# Mongoose findbyid() return null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to find a record in my mongo db by its id

No matter I use findbyid(), findone(id,...), it return null

here is my code. what is the solution?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Movie', {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => console.log('Connected to Databse'))
.catch(err => console.err('Could not connect to MongoDB', err));

var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [String],
    date: Date, 
    isPublished: Boolean,
    price: Number
});

const Data = mongoose.model('Datas', Schema);

async function updateData(id){
const result = await Data.findById(id);
console.log(result);
}
updateData('5a6900fff467be65019a9001');
```

Comment: Silly question: are you 100% sure the record is there in the DB?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have use findone() by the 'name' in my database, it return sth. But not work in '_id'

Comment: you are passing string whereas findById want objectId. Try with objectid

Comment: @Sid is right.. You probably don't have this specific record in your db... Running the exact same code works for me.. 
Just add `Data.create({}).then(console.log)` and copy the returned id to your updateData function...

Comment: here is a funny point, The _id which is hard code inside the database, is a String type. I just realise it few second ago.Thus, findbyid always not work. Now Problem solved. Thanks everyone

Comment: Please read my answer on this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58705908/4687359 Hope find it useful.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had the same problem. The _id in my DB collection was a `String`. After I enabled mongoose debug `require('mongoose').set('debug', true)`, I found out that the mongoose query `id` as `ObjectId("yourId")` unless we define `_id`  in the Schema. In order to solve the problem I had to add `_id:String` in to mongoose schema.

```
const MyDataSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
...
...
}
```

Comment: this actually saves my 2-3 hours :)

Comment: `const MyDataSchema = new Schema({
_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
...
...
}`

Comment: If we add _id to schema, then if we try to save a new document in mongo, it throws error "document must have an _id before saving". I don't think adding _id to the schema is the right solution for it.

Comment: Yeahhh man, thank you this happened to me after updating the mongoose version

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple solution to this:

Replace

```
const result = await Data.findById(id);
```

with

```
const result = await Data.findById(id).exec();
```

See [Mongoose - What does the exec function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do) for an explanation on what `exec()` does

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 3):

Check your mongodb database, if `_id` is storaged as String, `findById(id)` can not found `id`. `FindById(id)` only `finds ObjectId('yourId')`. 
You might import database by using mongoimport and including `_id` in JSON, it's wrong, delete `_id` in imported JSON.

Answer (score 3):

After hour of searching i needed to add _id to Schema like this:

```
  _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
```

Comment: Exactly my issue!! thank you :) 
I had it as a String but since it is saved as objectId it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. Then I referred to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52324642/3776376) Make sure the documents in the collection have **_id** as an **Object** rather than a **String**. If you have imported the database entries using a JSON file, just remove all the _id fields and then import it.

After importing, MongoDB will itself assign the **_id** values to all the entries.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the imported file used to have the _id column as string, so it was messing the DB and I was no able to filter using that column.

Once I deleted the collection, removed the _id column from data file and re-imported it, the _id filtering started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. It was simply solved by using findOne method instead of findById method of mongoose.

findOne syntax -

```
findOne({id: id-of-user},function(err,foundUser){
console.log(foundUser);
});
```