# findById in mongoose returns null for a certain schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema called `subcategory`:

```
const subCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
})
```

However when executing this: `const subCategoryRecord = await this.subCategoryModel.findById("idAsString")` i get null

I read about other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147649/mongoose-findbyid-return-null)
(says here that i should send `new ObjectId('id')` instead of `string`)

but i have another schema called `category`, and while doing `findById` by sending a string i DO get a result, what is the difference?

that's the category schema:

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
})
```

this WORKS: `const category = await this.categoryModel.findById('categoryIdAsString')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't specified the `_id` field in your `Schema` it will be of type `ObjectId`. For `findById` you can pass `id` as a `String` and Mongoose will convert it to `ObjectId` for querying.

Since you are getting a `null` response(no casting errors) I think you are passing a valid `ObjectId` string to the query and there might not be any record matching the provided `id`

You can use the below method to check if you are passing a valid `id`.

```js
mongoose.isValidObjectId(idAsString)
```

Answer (score 0):

The _id is an object even if when tested with "type of" it will say it's a string.
In my case this worked in the model :

```
authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "users" }
```

also if you ever need to compare an _id to and id saved as string you can use .equals() that will return a boolean :

```
user.userId.equals(checkUser._id)
```