# (node:6316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to edit and update the form data to MongoDB database using PUT method. But when I try to edit and click on save button in form, it is throwing below error:

```
(node:6316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at router.put (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\routes\articles.js:38:53)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Javascript\BlogApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

Router code (**articles.js**):

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const articleRouter = require("./routes/articles");
const Article = require("./models/article.model");

router.put("/:id", async (res, req) => {
  const article = await Article.findById(req.params.id);
});
```

Below is my model/schema code (**article.model.js**)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const marked = require("marked");
const slugify = require("slugify");
const createDomPurify = require("dompurify");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const dompurify = createDomPurify(new JSDOM().window);

const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  markdown: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  sanitizedHtml: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

articleSchema.pre("validate", function (next) {
  if (this.title) {
    this.slug = slugify(this.title, { lower: true, strict: true });
  }

  if (this.markdown) {
    this.sanitizedHtml = dompurify.sanitize(marked(this.markdown));
  }

  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog_Article", articleSchema);
```

Please help me out. I need to submit this assignment on priority :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the order of `req` and `rep`  parameter need to be changed.

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
```

Comment: Error is resolved by changing an order, but not able to save the updated records in the database, getting error as "TypeError: article.save is not a function". Below is the code.

router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
  var article = Article.findById(req.params.id);
  try {
    article.save();
    // console.log(article);
    res.redirect("/");
  } catch (error) {
    // console.log(error);
    res.render("articles/edit", { article: article });
  }
});

Comment: I'm not good at mongoose, but after some searching, found some solutions.(but may not be solution!).     
refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147649/mongoose-findbyid-return-null   
I think you would better print value and typeof article, id..